# How would I detect and group recurring methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I go about detecting recurring methods and grouping them by an identifier when calls to the recurring methods are asynchronous?

To demonstrate the use of time taken before the `callback` is called, `setTimeout` is being used.

```
var counter = 0

var foo = (function () {
    var context

    return function foo (callback) {
        if (!context) {
            context = {id: ++counter}
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            callback.call(context)
            context = null
        }, 1)
    }
}())

foo(function () {
    console.log(1, this.id)

    foo(function () {
        console.log(2, this.id)
    })
})

foo(function () {
    console.log(3, this.id)
})
```

The above code produces:

```
1 1
3 undefined
2 undefined
```

The desired result is:

```
1 1
3 2
2 1
```

Ideally, this would be achieved without having to use anything like `.bind` on the `foo` calls.

<s>I've experimented briefly with `arguments` (more specifically `arguments.callee`) and am aware I most likely need some way of duplicating `foo` with different `id`s, though I couldn't get any results which persisted the `id` on the `arguments.callee` function returned.</s>

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers so far! These are perfect answers for the question, but my use case does take a step further.

In the current scenario, the callback may be called asynchronously at an indeterminate time, meaning `context` slides back to `null` before I need it to.

I've edited the above code and explanation to reflect that new issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "methods" in this context. Do you know what `this` refers to in your example? What you want could be achieved with https://jsfiddle.net/hss5pfj0/, but whether that's a reasonable approach depends on what you are really trying to achieve with that.

Comment: @FelixKling That is indeed a reasonable approach and works beautifully, however it has highlighted an issue one step ahead that's explained some of my previous difficulties!

Have edited my question. Let me know if I can improve it further.

Comment: @FelixKling Your example uses `.call` which is analogous to `.bind`, but the op asked if there's a way to not use 'binding'. I'm pretty sure there answer is no, you need to bind.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable in a closure around the `foo` method that stores if the method is currently "being called". It's hard to explain, but this is what it would look like:

```
var foo = (function() {
  var locked;

  return function (callback) {
    if (!locked) {
      counter += 1;
      this.id = counter;
    } 

    locked = true;

    // Any time this callback calls 'foo', 
    // it will see it is locked and not increase the id
    callback();

    locked = false;
   }
 }());
```

```js
var counter = 0;
var foo = (function() {
  var locked;

  return function(callback) {
    if (!locked) {
      counter += 1;
      this.id = counter;
    }

    locked = true;

    // Any time this callback calls 'foo', 
    // it will see it is locked and not increase the id
    callback();

    locked = false;
  }
}());

foo(function() {
  log([1, this.id])

  foo(function() {
    log([2, this.id])
  })
})

foo(function() {
  log([3, this.id])
})

function log(msgs) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<code>" + msgs.join(" ") + "</code><br />"); }
```